# Grails resources plugin

Tags: grails

Trying to get my head around grails and resources plugin. I have read it's installed already. I also have read it's not and you have to add it as a runtime plugin to the config file. 
So question is which is correct? When I try adding it to my Config.groovy file I get an error.

> | Error Error packaging application: Error loading Config.groovy: No
>   signature of method:
>   groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.runtime() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [:resources:1.2]

**Config.groovy file**

grails {

```
    plugins {
        runtime ':resources:1.2'
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

UPDATED POST :
Sorry after posting I read that it had to be in my build config but get different error now.

> 2014-02-17 15:03:44,111 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   payment-gateway:plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error
>   configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]:
>   com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2475)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1818)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
>     at
>   com.blockconsult.yuiminifyresources.YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper.map(YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper.groovy:28)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMapper.invoke(ResourceMapper.groovy:139)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMapper.invokeIfNotExcluded(ResourceMapper.groovy:128)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.applyMappers(ResourceProcessor.groovy:587)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:533)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_prepareSingleDeclaredResource_closure12.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:602)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.util.ResourceMetaStore.addDeclaredResource(ResourceMetaStore.groovy:29)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareSingleDeclaredResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:600)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_prepareResourceBatch_closure14.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:625)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessorBatch.each(ResourceProcessorBatch.groovy:8)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareResourceBatch(ResourceProcessor.groovy:621)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.resourcesChanged(ResourceProcessor.groovy:804)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:800)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1056)
>     at
>   ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     ... 26 more

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) for the plugin you need to install the plugin in your `BuildConfig.groovy` not `Config.groovy`

> To use the plugin, add this to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
   runtime ':resources:1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that needs to go in your BuildConfig:

```
plugins {
    runtime ':resources:1.2'
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
}
```